# Button/Span boolean logic to be consistent with javascript and vice versa

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, button, user-interface, html

I have a situation where there are lot of buttons (basically span with icons but act like buttons). Each button will be shadded when pressed with the help of css. This botton should be linked to a variable or function in the javascript. All i want is the button and javascript should be in sync which means when the button pressed the javascript variable should be true or when that js variable is true the button should be in pressed or ON state. I have done this logic but it doesn't look as best practice, as sometimes the UI button and javascript don't be sync. Is there a best way to do this? Also there should be a way to control group of button by one javascript function on its state

Note: I don't want to call Ajax or anything to communicate to the server. It is purely UI requirement.

## HTML

```
 <span onclick="applyPropertiesChanges('Text', textButton)"> <span id="switch"
            class="text_btn-background toolboxItem ui-icon btn-icon-enable btn-fontItalicIcon" /></span>
```

## JS

```
var textButton
function applyPropertiesChanges(type,value)
{
  if(type == 'Text')
 { textButton = !textButton;
  //Check the UI span 
  if(value && this.children.hasClass('btn-icon-enable') &&)
{ 
 //UI span is on
//do nothing
}else{
  if(!value && !this.children.hasClass('btn-icon-diable')
 {// do nothing
 } else 
{
// Toggle the class of the span
}
}

 }
}
```

Comment: Like any other question here: please show what you've done so far (add html+css+js to your question).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this a little easier if you just add an attribute or class to the span.  Then you can check which ones have that attribute:

```
 <span class="btn"> <span id="switch"
            class="text_btn-background toolboxItem ui-icon btn-icon-enable btn-fontItalicIcon" /></span>

$('.btn').click(function() {
   $(this).addClass('data-clicked');
   $('.btn').not(this).removeClass('data-clicked');
});
```

Now when you click you can easily know which one was clicked by: `$('.btn.data-clicked')` and enable disable based on that.